# How to add text over multiple table cells?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a table with 20 rows and 24 cells. I want to display a label on one or more cell, that is when clicking one table cell, 3 or 4 cell including that cell should merged and make a common label for that cell at center aligned. But I don't want to use colspan, because I have already used the indexes of cells, it should not be changed. anyone have any idea. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So how many cells to be merged? 3 or 4?

Comment: Actually it is an application for assigning job for technician. the number of cells shows the technicians working duration like 1 hr,1.15 hr. Each cell is 15 minutes duration, duration depends on the hours given to the technician, so it will assign dynamically. so sometimes it will be 3,4 or 10 cells.